# MVVM Light Messenger Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Can anybody provide samples/links/simple-illustrations/videos/demos on how to use the messenger class in MVVM Light?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look into the source code of MVVM Light on CodePlex:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/47157

If you look into the samples, you will see that the CleanShutdown example uses the Messenger class.

Comment: That was really helpful. This particular link explains it very well:http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/10/18/clean-shutdown-in-silverlight-and-wpf-applications.aspx

Answer (score 5):

[Blog of Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx)

[MVVM light - how to access property in other view model on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699328/mvvm-light-how-to-access-property-in-other-view-model/2700324#2700324)

Answer (score 0):

In the [IssueVision.SL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionForSilverlight.aspx) example application, the messenger pattern is used to catch menu clicks and let the mainpage switch the views.