# The same property in two ViewModels and the property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have three ViewModels:
- MainViewModel,
- NavigatorViewModel,
- ProjectViewModel.

In the MainViewModel I have a property called CurrentProject from type ProjectViewModel:

```
public ProjectViewModel CurrentProject
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentProject;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentProject == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _currentProject = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProject");
        }
    }
```

In the NavigatorViewModel I have also a property CurrentProject

```
public ProjectViewModel CurrentProject { get { return ViewModelLocator.DesktopStatic.CurrentProject; } }
```

I use MVVM light. The View NavigatorView doesnt get notified if the property CurrentProject in the MainViewModel is changed.

How can I let the NavigatorView know, that the property has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a design concern, I would recommend not using a static Singleton pattern for this. You could use the `Messenger` class to send messages.

However, to address your current problem, you need to respond to the `PropertyChanged` event on the Singleton for that property:

```
public class NavigatorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NavigatorViewModel()
    {
        // Respond to the Singlton PropertyChanged events
        ViewModelLocator.DesktopStatic.PropertyChanged += OnDesktopStaticPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnDesktopStaticPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Check which property changed
        if (args.PropertyName == "CurrentProject")
        {
            // Assuming NavigatorViewModel also has this method
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProject");
        }
    }
}
```

This solution listens for changes to the Singleton property and propagates the change to listeners of `NavigatorViewModel`.

**Warning:** Somewhere in the `NavigatorViewModel` you need to unhook the event or you risk a memory leak.

```
ViewModelLocator.DesktopStatic.PropertyChanged -= OnDesktopStaticPropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works pretty good. Do you have an article about using the Messenger in the same way? I can't imagine how this works. I personally used it only in Messaging between View and Viewmodel. Do you mean that if I Change the property that I have to submit a message?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911171/mvvm-light-messenger-class.

Comment: Also, if that helps, please mark the answer as the solution. Cheers.