# How to pass an object from a xaml page to another?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

Passing value to another xaml page can be done easily with

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));`

But that is only for string values. I would like to pass an object to the xaml page. How do I do that?

Found a similar question on SO and WP7 forum. The solution is to use a global variable (not the nicest solution).

[WP7: Pass parameter to new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143383/wp7-pass-parameter-to-new-page)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/81ca8713-809a-4505-8422-000a42c30da8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the default code created when you start a new DataBound Project. It shows a way of passing a reference to a selected object to a details page.

Comment: Thanks. The default project pass the object indirectly via query string, which then access from `App.ViewModel`. That will work, but I was hoping to have a more elegant solution of passing the object directly.

Comment: i think there is no elegant solution, so got to do this indirect way. otherwise, use a framework.

Comment: There is an elegant solution, please look at my answer

Answer (score 5):

Using OnNavigatedFrom method

OnNavigateFrom is called when we call the NavigationService.Navigate method. It has a NavigationEventArgs object as a parameter that returns the destination page with its Content property with which we can access a property of the destination page "DestinationPage.xaml.cs"

First, in the destination page "DestinationPage.xaml.cs", declare a property "SomeProperty":

```
public ComplexObject SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Now, in "MainPage.xaml.cs", override the OnNavigatedFrom method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
// NavigationEventArgs returns destination page "DestinationPage"
    DestinationPage dPage = e.Content as DestinationPage;
    if (dPage != null)
    {
        // Change property of destination page 
        dPage.SomeProperty = new ComplexObject();
    }
}
```

Now, get the SomeProperty value in "DestinationPage.xaml.cs":

```
private void DestinationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This will display a the Name of you object (assuming it has a Name property)
    MessageBox.Show(this.SomeProperty.Name);
}
```

Comment: While this approach may work to pass a reference to a destination page, it will not work to receive the same reference in the source page when the destination release control back to the source.  There is no guarantee that the destination page's reference is valid after control is returned to the source page.

In general, the only real solution is to have a shared object reference stored in the current application object (Application.Current), to which both the source and destination pages have access and which is guaranteed to always remain valid during the lifetime of the app instance.

Comment: My answer is valid for the question as it is stated. I'd recommend you to transform your scenario in to a question (with code), and I'll try to answer it without using an ugly global in Application.Current (so far I have always been able to avoid them)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at Caliburn.Micro!

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks I will look into this framework (have heard it couple of times). Do you know if it can pass object to pages?

Comment: Binding to the ViewModel/Presenter/Controller/Screen behind should probably manage this!