# How to pass child windows usercontrol page values to another page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I designed the usercontrol for forgot password page.Then i need to send some of the textbox values to another page when button click in child windows page.please help me ....

Comment: if you aren't using a ViewModel you may store such data in static field accesed by App.xaml, for example.

Comment: I need to Navigate to another page from child page .please tell me synatax for that..

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml?yourValue=" + yourTextBox.Text, UriKind.Relative));

Comment: The above NavigationService.Navigate not working in child window usercontrol..."error like an object reference for the non static filed"..

Comment: try (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(uri);

Comment: childwindows control values in code behind not coming.i.e chlild.xaml page control values not accessing in child.xaml.cs page.please tell me how to access that..

Comment: the above statement Getting " System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); error .

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216049/passing-values-from-one-form-to-another-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

there are various way to do this.

you could actually declare a global variable in App.cs and assign the value to the global variable and then retrieve it back in the other page.

otherwise you could also do NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml?yourValue=" + yourTextBox.Text, UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you'll need to pass the parameters in the Uri when you call the new page.  There are several good explanations and examples on this page, also on Stack Overflow: [passing values from one form to another in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216049/passing-values-from-one-form-to-another-in-windows-phone-7)