# Get selected item of ListBox on another page

Tags: vb.net, listbox, windows-phone-8

I have made an application with two pages. When the user clicks an item on the listbox of the first page, the second page is supposed to show up with details about the clicked item.

I have a problem with accessing the selected item in the listbox of the first page from the second page.
How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because after navigation the first page no longer exists. You have to pass that value first:

[How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way - to pass data by navigation parameter, it is just like GET HTTP method, Nokia has an example of how to do it [here.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Passing_parameters_while_navigating_between_pages_on_Windows_Phone)

Second way - to store value in IsolatedStorage, for example in IsolatedStorageSettings , [here Microsoft topic](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx&ei=nhZGUdTIKcvo4QT44YGYAg&usg=AFQjCNF_PzsvQNKk27Ex2GhJfwGjxJejKg&sig2=ABWJFsf4FUOZb0MtEF9XOw&bvm=bv.43828540,d.bGE&cad=rjt) about it.