# How to pass values from one page to another in windows 8 contact custom app C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8

I need help on the following please. I have a windows 8 contact custom app. after i have added the contacts using the app. I have a page that displays all the contact list using Long list selector control. I then added A Tap event to the DisplayName textblock when the user click on the displayed name. the details for that contact details can be displayed to the next page. How can I pass other values, eg. the email, telephone, name to the next page. If you want the source code. I am happy to send it. thanks in advance...

Comment: Show your code where you stuck

Comment: See the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages

you can pass a class as a parameter

Comment: thanks Jerome... this worked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages