# C # App access to variables from other classes?

Tags: windows-store-apps

How can I access from a variable in MainPage.cs like "public static int intHallo = 5;" in another class of an App like BlankPage2.cs? Static does not work?

Greetings from Hannover
Christian

Comment: // MainPage.cs:
public class show
{
    int intZahl = 5;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    show intZahl = new show();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), intZahl);
}

// Page2.cs:
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{            
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    MainPage.show intZahl = (MainPage.show)e.Parameter;
    Test.Text = intZahl.ToString();
}` intZahl is always null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a global variable, define these in App.Xaml.cs

```
public static int IntHallo = 5

public static new App Current
    {
        get { return Application.Current as App; }
    }
```

Then you can use it on the OnNavigated to.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Test.Text  = App.IntHallo;
    }
```

If you want to pass parameters between XAML pages, follow this:
[How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages)