# Hide Button On other Page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to hide **button on Page2**, on click of **button on Page1** but it does not seem to work.

> Page 1 : btnRemove
>
> Page 2 : btnEdit

Below is code that i am trying.

```
 private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
            Page2 page = new Page2();
            page.btnEdit.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Bind your button visibility to a static field in your Page2, and from you page1, change this visibility (don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and set datacontext to work)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages

Comment: @cdie I am very new to WPF ,can you please elaborate a bit more.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to your XAML code change the button definition by adding the following

```
Visibility="{binding ButtonVisibility}"
```

create a new class called ButtonViewModel.cs here is the code

```
class ButtonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ButtonViewModel(Visibility visibility)
    {
        _buttonVisibility = visibility;
    }
    private Visibility _buttonVisibility ;

    public Visibility ButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _buttonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _buttonVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtonVisibility");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}
```

in page2.cs add this constructor

```
 public Page2(Visibility visibilty)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ButtonViewModel(visibilty);
    }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ButtonViewModel(Visibility.Visible);
    }
```

go to the button event handler and add this code

```
        NavigationWindow nvw = new NavigationWindow();
        nvw.Content = new Page1(Visibility.Collapsed);
        nvw.Show();
```

it is working as it should with me

Comment: Instead of     private Visibility [...] use private static Visibility