# Data passing windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a windows phone 8.1 app that has 2 forms: the `mainPage` and the `secondePage`.

The `mainPage` is the page that loads first, and I have a button to go to `secondePage`, then I must pass some data from `secondePage` to `mainPage` and that's when I got a NullReferenceException because the data I "passed" didn't actually pass.

I tried some code I found here on stackoverflow and in some tutorials but it didn't work because they use an expression in the `OnNavigatedTo` function and I'm passing data from second to `mainPage`. Can you help me find a way to get this data passed?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try using Isolated Storage? for example you could save the data eg - text from a textbox and have at load up when you open the second page? just some food for thought

Comment: Isolated Storage is better suited for the app to 'remember' variables like user settings when the app is restarted. For this user's problem I think it would be better to have a static, public, utility class where information can be read/written across different pages.

Comment: this is true, however he could still use isolated storage and have it reset each time he opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your code, but to save you time, view this link:

- [How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages)

You may find the answer at that link as it answers these questions:

1. When navigating between pages in an XAML application how do you pass
   parameters?
2. What is the difference between using the Uri navigation
   and manual navigation?
3. How can objects (not just strings) be passed when using Uri navigation?

If this answered your question, please mark this as answered.

Comment: You have two almost identical answers. Please delete one of them.