# Pass value from one xaml page to another xaml page in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0

Hello I am very new to Silverlight and I want to pass value from one Xaml page to another Xaml page in Silverlight. I got some solution for that as

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?key1"=txtname.Text, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

but I am finding an error in it as

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, property System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)'

Comment: Try this link its helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages

Comment: i am getting an error as: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)' ,so the solution is not mentioned in your link

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. unless that is a typo

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?key1"=txtname.Text, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

should change to...

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?key1="+txtname.Text, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Note the change from

> "/Page1.xaml?key1"=txtname.Text

to

> "/Page1.xaml?key1="+txtname.Text