# Find an element on new Page on Windows Phone 7/8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to instance new page and get the object on that page (for example LongListSelector) by the name.

But when I do

```
        var currentPage = (PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).Content;
        currentPage.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(pageUri, UriKind.Relative));
```

I can't get the instance of new page. The second calling of var currentPage = (PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).Content gets me the same currentPage.

How can I access the instance of new page and items on it? 
I need it to implement custom item selector. When tapping on the list item_header from page1 the page2 is showing, where I can chose the right item_kind and navigate back to list1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it with saving page instance in OnNavigateTo event into a global array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually looking for is passing data between pages or having a ViewModel that can be accessed from different pages and share data between them. Please have a look at the answer for that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page)

It describes the different ways of sharing data between pages.