# How to initiate a property of xaml page from an other xaml?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am quite new to wp development and i am developing an wp8 app which has a xaml page with a public property. Before navigating to this page, the property must be inititated. So when the page is loaded i can use the initiated property to create the page content. How can i initiate the proprty (from an other xaml file)?

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
               //initiate the property of Test.xmal here or ...???
               NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Test.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

             }
        }
public partial class Test: PhoneApplicationPage  

     {
            private list<pages> _pages; //The property       

            public Test()
            {                   
                InitializeComponent();
                //Build the page dynamically using _Pages  
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access properties on a different page and shouldn't.

What you are actually looking for is passing data between pages or having a ViewModel that can be accessed from different pages. Please have a look at the answer for that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page)

It describes the different ways of sharing data between pages.