# How to pass multiple data between pages in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In window phone, i use the following code to transfer data between pages,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?object1=" & obj, UriKind.Relative));
```

Here i'm passing one object between pages, what should i do to pass two objects between pages??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by object. Do you mean an ACTUAL object that inherits from Object or do you mean a value such as String value or int value.

regardless:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?object1="+obj+"&object2="+obj2, UriKind.Relative));
```

This should work for you.

Comment: You only can pass strings between pages in this way. Use PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyObject"] to save any object you would like to pass.

Answer (score 13):

### Update:

The answer of this question is a better solution: [Passing data from page to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page)

- Code:

  ```
  PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyObject"] = yourObject;
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/view/Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

  //In the Page.xaml-page
  var obj = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyObject"];
  ```

---

You can just add parameters to the URL, like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?object1=" + obj + "&object2=" + obj2, UriKind.Relative));
```

Otherwise, create a wrapper object that holds all of your object (like used in the MVVM pattern):

```
public class Container
{
    public object Object1 { get; set; }
    public object Object2 { get; set; }
}

var container = new Container { Object1 = obj, Object2 = obj2 };
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?object1=" + container, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I have the same doubt, how can I get the container object in the page view?

Comment: @danielrvt did you check my update? Check the link to the other question in my answer for more info. :)

Comment: @danielrvt, you need this method on the page:

`protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //code with the Container like the Abbas answer
        }`

Comment: Prefer the first method.

Comment: @Tealc Wu: that is also the better approach.

Comment: @Abbas so how can i take this values from another page ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to read [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2011/08/25/passing-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-7/)

Also, you should learn about MVVM pattern and try to use it!
About MVVM you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: 1st link is broken, plus you just cannot say go and learn whole MVVM for every single question about WP development.