# Send data from one page to Other page in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to send data from one page to another page in windows phone 8 using c# other than by using query string method?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page

Answer (score 0):

In First page set value like this

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Key"] = you value
```

In Second Page Get value which is set in First Page

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
         try
            {
             base.OnNavigatedTo(e);                   
              if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Count > 0)
              {
               var val = (SpeedTest)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Key"];
          PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove(AppConstant.SPEED);
               }  

              }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
            }
      }
```