# How can i get the value of a variable from a navigated form in Windows Phone?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

Since the Windows phone form is not modal,
how can i get the value of the selected color which is set at the ColorPicker.xaml ?

```
    Dim FirstBand As Res.Color
    Dim SecondBand As Res.Color

       Private Sub TextBlock_Tap(sender As Object, e As GestureEventArgs)
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/ColorPicker.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
            FirstBand = ColorPicker.SelectedColor
            txtFisrt.Text = FirstBand.ToString
        End Sub

        Private Sub TextBlock1_Tap(sender As Object, e As GestureEventArgs)
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/ColorPicker.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
            SecondBand = ColorPicker.SelectedColor
            txtSecond.Text = SecondBand.ToString
        End Sub
```

Comment: You can read more about [passing data between Pages here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4953491/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the url or set some static values in a Static class or in App class.

Comment: I have done so. The problem is that the FirstBand value is set before the ColorPicker form closes.

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: The three lines of code are executed at once. I would like the lines 2 and 3 to be executed after the navigation form Colorpicker.xaml has completed.

Comment: You should be able to do that overriding `OnNavigateFrom`