# Data Sharing In between Xaml pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing my first windows phone app and its a weather app.I have a List in the main page which would display the country name and the current temperature.Now when I click on any one country in the list the page is navigated to the Xaml page which would show the detailed information about the weather conditions.

But the problem I am facing is when I navigate to another Xaml page from there then it should give me the detailed contents of the next country in the list in same format as previous.

Can I know how is this possible as I am pretty new in this field.

Thanks in advance

**Code for List**

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" DataContext="{Binding listData}" IsGroupingEnabled="False" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image Name="condition" Source="{Binding Imagetype}" Height="80"   />
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tap="StackPanel_Tap" Height="100" Width="270" >
                                <TextBlock Name="CountryName" Text="{Binding Country}" FontFamily="Times new roman" TextWrapping='Wrap' Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="25" Width="250" Height="30"/>

                                <TextBlock Name="Temp" Text="{Binding Temp}" FontFamily="times new roman" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                                       FontSize="20" Width="250" Height="25"
                                       ></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3">
                                <Image Name="Button" Source="{Binding Remove}" Height="75" Width="75" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tap="Button_Tap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**Code for the Detailed Xaml Page**

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,432,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding WindSpeed}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Temperature}" FontFamily="SegoeWPLight" FontSize="240" Margin="44.791,43.086,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374.478" Height="363.881" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform SkewY="0.314" TranslateY="0.741"/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>

            </TextBlock>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="25,370,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="157,370,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="303,370,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,32,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <!--    <StackPanel Margin="12,0,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">-->
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="-10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid Name="WeeklyUpdate" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1652" Height="233">
                <!-- <Image Name="Image12"  Source="/Images/MenuIcons/w_thunder_cloud_rain.100.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="1430,0,0,102" MouseEnter="Image12_MouseEnter"/>-->
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="235*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="231*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="235*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="235*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="240*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- <Image Name="Image12"  Source="/Images/MenuIcons/w_thunder_cloud_rain.100.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="1430,0,0,102" MouseEnter="Image12_MouseEnter"/>-->
                <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="w_cloud_rain.100.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="54,50,0,0"  />
                <Image x:Name="Image2" Source="w_sun_cloud_wind.180.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="48,50,0,0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image x:Name="Image3" Source="w_cloud_rain.180.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="60,50,0,0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image4" Source="w_sun_cloud_wind.100.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="70,50,0,0"  Grid.Column="3"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image5" Source="w_sun_cloud_wind.140.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="74,50,0,0"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image6" Source="w_sun_cloud_wind.180.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="68,50,0,0"  Grid.Column="5"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image7" Source="w_thunder_cloud_rain.100.png" Height="102" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="63,50,0,0"  Grid.Column="6"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Max1}"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min1}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,152,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tomorrow" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Max2}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Min2}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,152,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Friday" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Max3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Saturday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" Margin="87,152,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Max4}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Margin="38,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min4}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Margin="161,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sunday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Margin="84,152,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Max5}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Margin="34,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min5}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Margin="178,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Monday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Margin="101,152,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Max6}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" Margin="38,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min6}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="5" Margin="173,0,0,190"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tuesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" Margin="82,152,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Max7}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6" Margin="39,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Min7}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6" Margin="143,18,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wednesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6" Margin="63,152,0,0"/>


            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I want this Xaml page to be changed according to the list and swipe control.Kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code No code No FUN......

Comment: @DhavalPatel...I have edited the question and have added the code,kindly check once.

Comment: How would you take selected Item of List ?\

Comment: I am using an event to take the selected Item,StackPanel_Tap,Yeah but again am facing the problem in this,it will display only for the last entered city and not the other cities when selected.

Comment: I think you have to use SelectedItme property of LongListSelector

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could pass the data with the URL when moving to the new page as illustrated in [How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages) question made here earlier.

Or you could store the data in singleton, and update & read it from different places as shown in [Passing data from page to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page) question.