# Passing Data from Page to Page for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, navigation, save, windows-phone-8.1

I have the exact same question as [Passing data from page to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page), but only for Windows Phone 8.1 (opposed to Windows Phone 7).  Here is the question:

I'm looking for the best practice on how to pass data from page to page.

In Page A I have a button that fires off Page B.
On Page B I have 6 textboxes that allow the user to enter information. When the user is done, the click on a button that brings them back to Page A.

I want to pass that data back to Page A.

I've seen suggestions to:

build XML documents and save to Isolated Storage
use the App class to store information in properties
pass it like a query string
I'm looking for the Best practice. Is there one that Microsoft recommends or one that is generally accepted as the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In WP8.1 Runtime - for *Silverlight*, [the methods used in WP8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4953491/2681948) still should work - you have couple of choces:

- the first and probably the easiest way is to use [Navigate with parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx) - you don't have to convert it to *string* if it's a serializable type:

  ```
  // let's assume that you have a simple class:
  public class PassedData
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Value { get; set; }
  }

  // then you navigate like this:
  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), new PassedData { Name = "my name", Value = 10 });

  // and in target Page you retrive the information:
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      PassedData data = e.Parameter as PassedData;
  }
  ```
- you can use some *static objects* to pass your data along the App
- finally as you have mentioned you can save your data in: *LocalSettings*, *LocalStorage*, *LocalCache* - thought in this case you will also have to serialize it to XAML, Json or other.

Note that you will also have to handle app suspending/resuming - so it will be suitable to save your data when the app is being suspended and load when it's resumed. You should remember that *OnNavigatedTo* is not being called when the app is resuming.

---

The above was about normal navigation (forward). If you want to fill some data in previous Page, then you have a couple of options:

- pass a handler to a previous Page, so you can access public variables/properties from current Page,
- use a static variable/property - maybe a singleton
- again use files/settings

Note that again the first two methods has a disadvantage that the app may crash after being suspended. Saving to files might be better here, thought needs some more work and proper handling.

Comment: if we want to pass more than one parameter then what approach is better?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar It depends on types of your parameters, how important they are and other implementations.

Comment: I want to pass an object of class and a string paramater which is from some other class.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar It depends if your class consists of basic types. Give it a try and choose the most appropriate method for you. Don't forget about ap suspension and even termination.

Answer (score 0):

--First Create a class

```
public class PassedData
{
   public string email { get; set; }  
}
```

--then You can navigate within pages hanging the value

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Frame2), new PassedData { email = emailtxt.Text });
```

--then catch the value that passing in another page

```
var passedData = e.Parameter as PassedData;

emailtxt.Text = passedData.email;
```