# Returning data to a previous page Windows Phone 8.1 Windows RunTime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking for a **simple** way to return data from a form.
I am trying to populate a text box on **form 1** with data returned from **form 2**. This is the code used to navigate to **form 2**:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(form 2));
```

And I know you can pass a parameter back to **form 1** using this method, but when back is pressed it would go to **form 2** which is not ideal as I want it to go back to **form 0**.

Can you return data using this or something similar:

```
 Frame.GoBack();
```

Additionally, are the only methods for transferring data between pages:

> pass a handler to a previous Page, so you can access public variables/properties from current Page,
>
> use a static variable/property - maybe a singleton
>
> again use files/settings

As said in [Passing Data from Page to Page for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946575/passing-data-from-page-to-page-for-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use the option number 2 in the list you mentioned - storing it in a simple static property? That's certainly a quick solution.

One other option, if you are using MVVM and a library such as MVVM Light, would be to send the value from the ViewModel connected to form 2, to the ViewModel connected to form 1, using a messenger.

Subscribing:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<TypeOfMessageYouWantToSend>(this, MethodWhichHandlesTheReceivedValue);
```

And sending:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<TypeOfMessageYouWantToSend>(msg);
```

You can send it when navigating back, or even while the form is being populated etc.

Comment: I was just hopeful :) Thank you very much!