# How to display passed information for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop a app for windows phone 8.1. I am complete beginner in app dev. Right now my question is - how can I displaay the information passed in another page inside a textbox or some sort. Its a shopping app and I am trying to get the name of the item which is a button, appear in the Basket page when the basket is clicked on. Code is below. So i.e. Item from Menu.xaml show up in Basket.xaml when button in Menu.xaml is selected.

**Basket.Xaml**

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;

    }
```

So say for example I have a txt box in Basket.xaml which aims to show the Item chosen in Menu.xaml how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second page (the basket one, if I understood correctly), you should be able to access the passed data, pretty easy :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var passedData = e.Parameter as PassedData; //cast the object back to PassedData type.
    someTextBlockOnBasket.Text = passedData.Name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data you want to pass is of primitive type you can pass like you did.
If not primitive data
You can store in LocalSettings. To do so you have to serialize your class to Json,xml

```
LocalSettings.Values[key]=Json Converter.Serialize(object)
```

But LocalSettings has some size restrictions, if data to be passed is very big you can serialize and store to a file and use that in next page

Here us code to serialize and deserialize

```
MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new 
            DataContractSerializer(typeof(Menu.PassedData;
));
serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, data);


StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                         .CreateFileAsync(sFileName);
using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
}
Deserialize back this way -


StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.
                           GetFileAsync(sFileName);
using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = 
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Menu.PassedData;
));
    var data = (Menu.PassedData;
)serializer
                     .ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
}
```

For more information please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946575/passing-data-from-page-to-page-for-windows-phone-8-1)