# How to display the xml data on the second page if we press the button which is on first page of the program?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an object from a xaml page to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302212/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-xaml-page-to-another)

I'm very new to windows phone development. I wanted to display the xml data on the second page. That means I have taken one button on the first page and if press this button it should show the data on the second page.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: Could you clarify, where do you get the xml data (or do you mean XAML)?

Comment: In my app i have added one xml file and from that file i want to display the some attributes of particular element. for example:- <ROOT><Region name = "Europe"><Country name = "United Kingdom"> <City name = "London"></City></Country></Region></ROOT> here from this xml i want to display the COUNRTY on the secondpage.xaml but before that i have taken one button on the firstpage.xaml if we click that button it should display that particular elements attributs on the secondpage.xaml i think i have made myself clear in this case.   Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Check these very similar questions:

[How to pass the image value in one xaml page to another xaml page in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213354/how-to-pass-the-image-value-in-one-xaml-page-to-another-xaml-page-in-windows-phon)

[Passing a complex object to a page while navigating in a WP7 Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701566/passing-a-complex-object-to-a-page-while-navigating-in-a-wp7-silverlight-applicat)

[How to pass an object from a xaml page to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302212/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-xaml-page-to-another)

[How to pass a value between Silverlight pages for WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637533/how-to-pass-a-value-between-silverlight-pages-for-wp7)

[How do I navigate from one xaml page to another, and pass values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438056/how-do-i-navigate-from-one-xaml-page-to-another-and-pass-values)