# How can I navigate and pass data between Pages?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml, mobile

I'm a bit of a beginner with this so i'll try and keep it simple.

I have a a xaml page with a button click event linking it to another xaml page. What I'm trying to do is on the click event take two strings and pass them to a text box on the second page.  Can you please show me a simple code example of how to do this?

Comment: the concept in this case is simple, make the second page to expose a method called SetValue and pass the strings to that method from the first page. In the Page2.SetValue you will assign the value received as parameter of the method to the proper TextBox. In this way a page does not know which controls are available on another page and this is correct and decouples things nicely so that if you change from TextBoxes to labels, nothing breaks except you change things where controls are...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from a xaml page to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302212/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-xaml-page-to-another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the button click event of the first page you do something like the following

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
         string urlWIthData = string.Format("/Page2.xaml?name={0}", txtName.Text);  
         this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlWIthData, UriKind.Relative));  
    }
```

On the desintation page, you do the following:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
     myTextBox.Text = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["name"].ToString();  
}
```