# Passing page checkBox value to other class

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I've been reading other questions and pages and seen some ideas but could not understand them or get them to work properly.

My Example:

I have this checkBox1 on my mainpage.xaml

```
 <CheckBox Content="Central WC / EC" Height="68" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,206,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" />
```

I have a anotherpage.xaml with its c# on anotherpage.xaml.cs:

```
 public void Feed(object Sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked("SE" == (_item.Sector))) ; 
        {

        }
     }
```

How do I pass the value of the checkBox1 on the mainpage.xaml to the anotherpage.xaml.cs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143383/wp7-pass-parameter-to-new-page Check it out ;)

Comment: `Checked` is an event on the CheckBox. You probably want the `IsChecked` property to tell if the user has checked the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass whether the checkbox is checked when opening the next page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml?chkd=" + checkBox1.IsChecked, UriKind.Relative));
```

You could then query this in the `OnNavigatedTo` event on the "other" page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string isChecked;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("chkd", out isChecked))
    {
        if (bool.Parse(isChecked))
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
To pass multiple values just add them to the query string:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml?chk1=" + checkBox1.IsChecked + "&chk2=" + checkBox2.IsChecked, UriKind.Relative));
```

(You'll probably want to format the code a bit better though)

You can then get each parameter in turn from the

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string is1Checked;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("chk1", out is1Checked))
    {
        if (bool.Parse(is1Checked))
        {
            //
        }
    }

    string is2Checked;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("chk2", out is2Checked))
    {
        if (bool.Parse(is2Checked))
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

As you want to pass more and more values this will get messy with lots of duplicate code. Rather than pass multiple values individualy you could concatenate them all together:

```
var checks = string.Format("{0}|{1}", checkBox1.IsChecked, checkBox2.IsChecked);

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml?chks=" + checks, UriKind.Relative));
```

You could then split the string and parse the parts individually.

Comment: Hi Matt, this seems like an interesting solution. Can I use this to pass multiple checkboxes? I have 8 in total. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan updated answer to include 2 ways of handling multiple check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public property in the App class.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public int Shared { set; get; }
    //...
}
```

Then you can access it from the pages via:

```
(Application.Current as App).Shared
```

You could store a reference to the form or put an event or anything else you want to do.

On a side note, I highly recommend [Petzold's WP7 book free for download](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html).