# How to pass a parameter to a local html page in WP7 / WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, url, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know how to pass a url parameter to a local page in the Web Browser Control?

When you navigate to the page alone `"/Html/MyPage.html"` all is well but as soon as you add a parameter `"/Html/MyPage.html?Message=Hello"` I get an error page stating that we could not navigate to the page.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143383/wp7-pass-parameter-to-new-page

That will help.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for the quick response. Actually I was referring to the Web Browser control with local HTML pages specifically rather than XAML pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another workaround you can pass your arguments as location hash parameter (if it is not used)

```
browser.Navigate(new Uri("www/index.html#p=123&p2=567", UriKind.Relative));
```

and then in index.html

```
var args = window.location.hash;
```

(args = '#p=123&p2=567')

Tested on WP7 (index.html is stored in isolated storage) + WP8 (index.html is loaded directly from XAP)

Comment: This is actually what I ended up using. Works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

As a dirty workaround that just works you can implement this as following:

A. Navigate to the page w/o any parameters

B. Attach arguments passing logic below to one of the following events

[WebBrowser.Navigated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.92%29) - when successfully navigated

[WebBrowser.LoadCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.92%29) - occurs after the WebBrowser control has loaded content.

C. Inject arguments to html page using [webBrowser.InvokeScript (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] {"processArgs('someArgs') or any generated/custom script"});
```

or

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("processArgs", new string[] {"someArgs"});
```

where processArgs is defined somewhere in your html file.