# Not able to pass data to child browser in windows phone

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am building a Windows Phone 7 hybrid application using PhoneGap.
    We are opening a child browser in our application.

```
The problem is we are not able to send some data to child browser window from our javascript file.We have tried to use local storage but local storage value are not accessible in child browser.

This is the section of code from where we are opening child browser.(parent browser)

$("#openformbtn").click(function(){
        ChildBrowser.install();     
localStorage.qString='h=NAS1&t=0000927686:1000&n=abc&e=a@g.com&c=776895654568&hname=mnl&cname=Ahm';
        var cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
        cb.showWebPage('x-wmapp1://app/www/payment-info.html',false);       
        });
        });

This code is called in child browser when it gets loaded(child browser)


$(document).ready(function(){
createPaymentInfo();
});


function createPaymentInfo(){
 var query= localStorage.qString;
     }
```

Comment: Could you post some toy example code?

Comment: Waahh... Can you append it to your question for better formatting? :D

Comment: check now.sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Append the data to the url.

```
$("#openformbtn").click(function(){
    ChildBrowser.install();     
    var qString='h=NAS1&t=0000927686:1000&n=abc&e=a@g.com&c=776895654568&hname=mnl&cname=Ahm';
    var cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
    var url = 'x-wmapp1://app/www/payment-info.html' + '?' + qString;
    cb.showWebPage(url, false);       
});
```

Then inside the child browser you can have some code like:

```
var params = location.href.split('?')[1];
```

and parse into an array or whatever from there.

Comment: I have already tried this solution.The child browser displays an error as : "We're having trouble displaying this web page"
and a navigation error comes.

Comment: hey it worked .I tried this link and first solution worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577114/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-local-html-page-in-wp7-wp8