# How can I listen in my ViewModel to changes from another ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the task to write a user control to display some results by using the MVVM patern.

The main application (called  `ApplicationVM`) has two a properties `UserControlViewModel` and `SelectedRecord`. The first property contains an instance of the `UserControlViewModel`. In XAML I use these property to bind the `UserControl` to the `UserControlViewModel`. The DependencyProperty `PageCount` is for simple notifications between a display function in the view and the `UserControlViewModel`.

```
<control:UserControl DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModel}" PageCount="{Binding DocumentPageCount}" />
```

Here is the implementation of the second property in the ApplicationViewModel.

```
public Record SelectedRecord
{
    get
    {
        return m_SelectedRecord;
    }
    set
    {
        m_SelectedRecord = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecord");
    }
}
```

Later, this property will by replaced. But what I should to do is to make a dependency between the property "`SelectedRecord`" and a "`Record`" of the "`UserControlViewModel`" which calls a function to generate the new content (e.g. `GenerateContent()`). How can I make it possible that a change of the `SelectedRecord` property updates the `Record` Property of the `UserControlViewModel` to genereate the new content? Or can my `UserControlViewModel` hear the `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecord")` to generate automaticcly new content?

Comment: Take a look at [ViewModelLocator](http://blog.roboblob.com/tag/viewmodellocator/)

Comment: You should use the Mediator pattern here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a messenger - that way your view models can be nicely decoupled.

Here's a thread on SO talking about the one in MVVM light:

[MVVM light - how to access property in other view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699328/mvvm-light-how-to-access-property-in-other-view-model)

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution would be to update the setter of your SelectedRecord property. Here you could call the GenerateContent method on the UserControlViewModel, and possibly also set the SelectedRecord property there if you need to.

Alternatively your UserControlViewModel could listen to the PropertyChanged event on the ApplicationVM, but to do that the UserControlViewModel would need a reference to the ApplicationVM.

Finally you could use an event system to communicate between your view models. This would ensure that your view models were nicely decoupled, but the price would be added complexity. Check out the documentation on the [Prism Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) if you are interested.